# Shortest way to initialize C++ vector with auto-generated values

Tags: c++, stl

I'm wondering if there's anything in the recent revisions of the C++ standard that would let me construct a vector and fill it with auto-generated values (say, from a RNG) in fewest keystrokes, and preferably in a single line.

The best I can think of is

```
int N=1000;
std::default_random_engine rng;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distr(0,99);

vector<int> v(N);
std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), std::bind(distr,rng));
```

or

```
std::generate_n(v.begin(), N, std::bind(distr,rng));
```

but it's so long that it actually takes fewer keystrokes to code an explicit initialization loop:

```
    for(auto& x: v)
        x=distr(rng);
```

I particularly dislike having .begin() and .end() there.

There does not appear to be the right constructor for vector that is capable of taking a functor initializer, but maybe there's some other approach.

Comment: prngs don't have a common interface as far as I know so I think the range based for-loop you've got there is as nice as it gets.

Comment: I don't mind wrapping the prng into a lambda, as long as I can avoid separating construction and initialization of the vector.

Comment: Just speculating, but would private composition + initial generation be ok?
When I think about it, why doesn't prngs have a common interface? Pretty annoying ...

Comment: You can avoid separate construction and initialization using `std::vector::reserve` and `std::back_inserter()` to `std::generate_n`.

Comment: I can't think of a shorter way than what you have except what I did is write a function for it. Now it's as simple as `random_vector(n, min, max);`

Comment: Building on @Galik's idea: can a `resize` be used to autoconstruct the vector with a generator? I'm not near a compiler so I can't try it out myself.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo the vector::resize has paramater lists of int and int, value_type &value. It does not call a functor to obtain the value. So one could resize a vector to a large amount but all the values would be the same

Comment: @johnathan No iterator-initialisation then... ok. That had been too easy :-)

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo you can range initialize a vector, but you can't generate one with a functor like what the OP is asking for without a loop or generate_n

Comment: ... or a (perhaps static) generator in the class itself? Anyway, the result would be the same. Thx @johnathan.